# Can I ignore this iphone warning?

Tags: iphone, warnings, mkannotation

I have this code:

```
if([annotation respondsToSelector:@selector(tag)]){
    disclosureButton.tag = [annotation tag];
}
```

and I get the warning:

> '-tag' not found in protocol

Fair enough, but I've created a new object with the  protocol that has a synthesized `int tag` variable.

EDIT: found why the app was crashing - not this line. Now I just get a warning and the app works fine.

Thanks
Tom

Comment: Have you tried enabling NSZombieEnabled?

Comment: You don't think its this line? What does the debugger have to say about that?

Comment: EXC_BAD_ACCESS - it was a variable I hadn't retained... so not that line at all. This line just gives me a warning. Will have a look at NSZombieEnabled... not sure what it does. :) thanks

Comment: NSZombieEnabled won't help. Its not a problem with releasing/retaining variables. The problem is the function passes my custom MKAnnotation `TCPlacemark : NSObject<MKAnnotation>` as `(id) <MKAnnotation>` (because there are other classes that may conform to the <MKAnnotation> protocol, as I'm sure you are aware). Nonetheless, because not all of these will respond to `-tag` just the `TCPlacemark` custom class, it is giving me this warning. My question therefore is, can I just ignore it. Its rather annoying to have the yellow triangle, but its not hindering my app at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The warning is generated because for the *static type* of `annotation`, `MKAnnotation`, there is no method `-tag`. As you already checked wether the *dynamic type* responds to the selector you can ignore the warning in this case.

To get rid of the warning:

- If you expect a certain class you can test for it instead:

  ```
  if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[TCPlaceMark class]]) {
      disclosureButton.tag = [(TCPlaceMark *)annotation tag];
  }
  ```
- For a protocol:

  ```
  if ([annotation conformsToProtocol:@protocol(PlaceProtocol)]) {
      disclosureButton.tag = [(id<PlaceProtocol>)annotation tag];
  }
  ```
- Or if both do not apply use a specific protocol to suppress the warning (useful e.g. with rapidly changing Apple APIs):

  ```
  @protocol TaggedProtocol
  - (int)tag;
  @end

  // ...
  if([annotation respondsToSelector:@selector(tag)]){
      disclosureButton.tag = [(id<TaggedProtocol>)annotation tag];
  }
  ```